# Docker image to cross compile node modules for RPI?

Tags: linux, node.js, cross-compilation, docker

I am wondering if anyone knows a way(preferably docker container) to use a Linux Machine, to cross compile a nodejs application, with native modules, such as serialport and run it on a RPI?

Thanks